# Why widgets are wrongly placed after executing my app?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio. When I tried to execute my demo app, the components are changed from their original position. Why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.kasamsp.myfirstapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Hi world"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.456"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.424" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="137dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="258dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Actual one:
[image]

After executing:
[image]

Comment: These are widgets, not components

Answer (score 1):

You are using ConstraintLayout. If you want to continue using it, you will have to place constraints on every widget you place in the UI. I, personally would recommend using RelativeLayout if you are new to Android Development until you figure out all the layout.
change this

`<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

and

`</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>`

to

`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

and

`</RelativeLayout>`